# Meaning of "It is written"

Tags: phrase-meaning, rhetoric

> It is written in the book

Does it mean that someone wrote something in the book and it's still there?
Or does it mean that someone writes it in the book?

Comment: Please, please provide more context. Where did you find this quotation?

Answer (score -1):

The phrase *it is written* is an appeal to written authority of some sort. It might be law, history, wisdom, prophecy, etc. You find it in the Bible, for example in Matthew 4:4:

> Jesus answered, "It is written: 'Man shall not live on bread alone, but on every word that comes from the mouth of God.'"

Here, Jesus is appealing to Jewish history by quoting from Deuteronomy 8:3:

> He humbled you, causing you to hunger and then feeding you with manna, which neither you nor your ancestors had known, to teach you that man does not live on bread alone but on every word that comes from the mouth of the Lord.

New International Version

Comment: I believe that the quotation is the one which I formatted, please check the edit, I don't think, (I may be wrong) that the OP is referring to the scriptures because anything could be "written in a book".

Comment: @Mari-LouA You may be right. It's difficult to tell without context.

Answer (score -1):

The idiomatic phrase

> it is written

is usually used to a reference a passage or story in the Bible.

> It is written "Thou shall not kill." *(one of the Ten Commandments)*