# "it has been written" vs "it is written"

Tags: passive-voice

What's the meaning of:

> It has been written in bible

To me, it sounds like "It was once written but it doesn't exist there anymore."

It should've been

> It is written in bible

because written is a state of being verb, like *drunk*, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of "It is written"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/118375/meaning-of-it-is-written)

Comment: 'It has been written' does not implies that it is not there anymore. It means that the process of writing something took place (and got completed) in the past. It may very much be still there.

Comment: I don't think the answers on the suggested duplicate actually answer *this* question. Neither of the current answers for that question address the difference between "it has been written" and "it is written".

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors in your line of thinking:

1) *written* is not really a state of being like *drunk*. We expect drunk people to sober up, but we don't expect written words to disappear.

2) to convey, "It was once written but it doesn't exist there anymore," I would say:

> It **had** been written in the Bible (not ***has** been written*)

3) This isn't a matter of one version is right and one version is wrong; both versions could be considered grammatically correct (although I would agree with you that, if the guidance can be found in the Bible, *is* is probably a better way to say it than *has been*).

4) We would typically use an article in this context:

> It is written in **the** Bible...
>   It is written in **a** book by Tolstoy...